# Database structuring for 'likes' or 'endorsements'

Tags: sql, database, database-design, relational-database

I am trying to develop an application in which users can have their own profiles, and profiles can show the users skills, and the skills can have endorsements by other users (or "likes", much like LinkedIn!).

I have a `profiles` table, and a `skill` table. These 2 tables have a many-to-many relationship (a profile can have many skills, and a skill can be linked to many profiles). I'm trying to keep the skill names `unique` when a new skill is stored in the db. I'm trying to have `endorsements` (or `likes`) for each skill that the user adds to his profile. Is there a standard or optimized way to solve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add an additional foreign key from the `endorsement` to the `profile` of the person doing the endorsement.  This tells you who likes who and what they like about them.

See this ERD:

[image: ERD]